# How to select even numerical values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySql table named nums in the following structure populated with numerical data.

```
id, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6    
01, 34, 11, 07, 32, 19, 08    
02, 17, 03, 45, 02, 06, 15
.., .., .., .., .., .., ..
```

---

My goal is to be able to select how many odd numbers are in a row and how many even numbers are in a row.

I have achieved the odd select statement as per below, but I am not sure how to do the equivalent for even numbers, any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

---

example: selecting how many rows have 3 odd numbers

```
  SET @NumbersOfOddColumnsWanted = 3;

  SELECT 
    n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6
  FROM
     nums
  WHERE
    n1 % 2 + n2 % 2 + n3 % 2 + n4 % 2 + n5 % 2 + n6 % 2 = @NumbersOfOddColumnsWanted
```

Comment: How about `6 - @NumbersOfOddColumnsWanted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has the nice feature that a "boolean" value is treated as 0 or 1.  So, you can add them up.

```
SELECT ((n1%2 = 0) + (n2%2 = 0) + (n3%2 = 0) + (n4%2 = 0) + (n5%2 = 0) + (n6%2 = 0)
       ) as NumEvens,
       ((n1%2 = 1) + (n2%2 = 1) + (n3%2 = 1) + (n4%2 = 1) + (n5%2 = 1) + (n6%2 = 1)
       ) as NumOdds
FROM nums;
```

This assumes that none of the values are `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Gordon Linoff, just what I needed